# How to load external data in Amcharts4

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

I'm trying out amCharts 4 at the moment and wanted to load my json in to the graph. Because my json is nested ive added a on parseended event to change my json structure. When i console log the new data it has the correct structure. But when i want to load it into the categories, it doesn't show anything. Currently I only want the categories to show up with no extra values yet.

**My component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})

export class ChartComponent {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart)

      chart.paddingRight = 30;
      chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

      var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
      colorSet.saturation = 0.4;
      chart.dataSource.url = "https://localhost:44321/api/upload/readFile";
      chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function (ev) {
        // parsed data is assigned to data source's `data` property
        var data = ev.target.data;
        var newData = [];
        data.forEach(function (dataItem) {
          var newDataItem = {};
          Object.keys(dataItem).forEach(function (key) {
            if (typeof dataItem[key] === "object") {
              newDataItem["_id"] = dataItem[key]["@id"];
            } else {
              newDataItem[key] = dataItem[key];
            }
          });
          newData.push(newDataItem);         
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
        return newData
      });

      var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "_id";
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
      categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;


      var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
      dateAxis.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
      dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 70;
      dateAxis.baseInterval = { count: 30, timeUnit: "minute" };
      dateAxis.max = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
      dateAxis.strictMinMax = true;
      dateAxis.renderer.tooltipLocation = 0;

      var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series1.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
      series1.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {openDateX} - {dateX}";

      series1.dataFields.openDateX = "fromDate";
      series1.dataFields.dateX = "toDate";
      series1.dataFields.categoryY = "name";
      series1.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color"; // get color from data
      series1.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
      series1.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

      chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

      chart.dataSource.events.on("error", function (ev) {
        console.log("Oopsy! Something went wrong");
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea for using `chart.dataSource.url` for loading external data.

To parse the external JSON and format it so it is suitable for the `chart`, `series`, or category axis `data`, it's better to utilize adapters. Adapters allow you to tweak things to your liking. We have a guide on that here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/

In this case, once the JSON is parsed, you can use the adapter for [`parsedData`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/#parsedData_adapter). The code would look like this (taken and fixed from [another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296481/amcharts-4-getting-nested-array-data)):

```
chart.dataSource.adapter.add("parsedData", function(data) {
  var newData = [];
  data.forEach(function(dataItem) {
    var newDataItem = {};
    Object.keys(dataItem).forEach(function(key) {
      if (typeof dataItem[key] === "object") {
        newDataItem["_id"] = dataItem[key]["@id"];
        dataItem[key]["Column"].forEach(function(dataItem) {
          newDataItem[dataItem["@name"]] = dataItem["@id"];
        });
      } else {
        newDataItem[key] = dataItem[key];
      }
    });
    newData.push(newDataItem);
  });
  data = newData;
  return data;
});
```

Here's a demo (also takes sample JSON from your other question, fixes the JSON, and the formatting logic):

https://codesandbox.io/s/r1mnjq192p

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the following line:
**replace this:** return newData **with this:** chart.dataSource.data = newData