# Amcharts 4 how to show all categories?

Tags: typescript, amcharts

I'm using amcharts4 and want to show all of the categories. Right now its hiding a lot of them and it stops at a certain categorie. I saw some solutions that used gridcount or something like this, but I don't know how this works in version 4 of amcharts.

**My component .ts:**

```
 import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
    import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
    import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
    import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
    import { DataSource } from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
    import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
    import { CategoryAxis } from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';
    
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-chart',
      templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
    })
    
    export class ChartComponent {
      constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart)
    
          chart.paddingRight = 30;
          chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
    
          var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
          colorSet.saturation = 0.4;
         
          chart.dataSource.url = "https://localhost:44321/api/upload/readFile";
          chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function (ev) {
            // parsed data is assigned to data source's `data` property
            var data = ev.target.data;
            var newData = [];
            data.forEach(function (dataItem) {
              var newDataItem = {};
              Object.keys(dataItem).map(function (key) {
                if (typeof dataItem[key] === "object") {
                  newDataItem["_id"] = dataItem[key]["@id"];
                  dataItem[key]["Column"].forEach(function (nestedItem, index) {
                    Object.keys(dataItem).map(function () {
                      newDataItem[nestedItem["@name"] + index] = nestedItem["#text"];
                    })
                  })           
                } else {
                  newDataItem[key] = dataItem[key];
                }
              });
              newData.push(newDataItem);
            });
            chart.dataSource.data = newData
            console.log(JSON.stringify(chart.dataSource.data));
            });
    
          chart.data = chart.dataSource.data;
    
          var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
          categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "TransactionID3";
    
          chart.dataSource.events.on("error", function (ev) {
            console.log("Oopsy! Something went wrong");
          });
        })
      }
    }
```

My graph currenty only added the categorie axis for demo purposes.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. What are these other categories? Where's it stopping? Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? [Here's a demo you can work off of/fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y2oy7mlwv) on CodeSandbox.io, it's a combination of code you posted here and [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296481/amcharts-4-getting-nested-array-data), which is not enough to figure out where you're getting stuck or what you're looking to do.